# Parsing xml-like data

Tags: php, xml, regex

I have a string with xml-like data:

```
<header>Article header</header>
<description>This article is about you</description>
<text>some <b>html</b> text</text>
```

I need to parse it into variables/object/array "header", "description", "text".

What is the best way to do this? I tried `$vars = simplexml_load_string($content)`, but it does not work, because it is not 100% pure xml (no `<?xml...`).
So, should I use `preg_match`? Is it the only way?

Comment: This is not xml. So `simplexml` does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XML string *looks like* (though may or may not be) an XML document fragment. PHP can work with this using the `DOMDocumentFragment` class.

```
$doc  = new DOMDocument;
$frag = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$frag->appendXML($content);

$parsed = array();
foreach ($frag->childNodes as $element) {
    if ($element->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
        $parsed[$element->nodeName] = $element->textContent;
    }
}

echo $parsed['description']; // This article is about you
```

Answer (score 0):

With a string like that, simlexml_load_string should work.

Because of the 3rd tag, if you try to get that it will fail, and not return the correct value (because there is a sub part within the tag.

Try something like this, which might work for you:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($content)
$text = $xml->text->asXML();
```

You should also take a look at this documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php. They also do the same thing with the string. You might wanna use this option instead of `simplexml_load_string` too

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
```

Comment: `simplexml_load_string` throws error when there is no `<?xml >` or top level element. `SimpleXMLElement` may be the way to go.